# Replace all emojis from a given unicode string

Tags: regex, python-2.7, unicode

I have a list of unicode symbols from the `emoji` package. My end goal is to create a function that takes as input a unicode a string, i.e. `something`, and then removes all emojis, i.e. `"something"`. Below is a demonstration of what I want to achieve:

```
from emoji import UNICODE_EMOJI
text = 'something'
exclude_list = UNICODE_EMOJI.keys()
output = ... = 'something'
```

I have been trying to do the above, and in that process, I came across a strange behavior which I demonstrate below, as you can see. I believe if the code below is fixed, then I will be able to achieve my end goal.

```
import regex as re
print u'\U0001F469'                     #    
print u'\U0001F60C'                     #     
print u'\U0001F469\U0001F60C'           #  

text = u'some\U0001F469\U0001F60Cthing' 
print text                              # something

# Removing "" works
print re.sub(ur'[\U0001f469\U0001F60C]+', u'', text)  # something
# Removing only "" doesn't work 
print re.sub(ur'[\U0001f469]+', u'', text)            # some�thing
```

Comment: (Confirmed for Mac OS X: the 3rd line reads `some???thing` for me. Hold on while I check what characters these are.)

Comment: I can reproduce this bug in Python 2.7.10 on Mac OS X 10.13.6.  Inserting `repr` in the `print` statement shows that the result of `re.sub` is `u'some\ude0cthing'`.  (Incidentally, `sys.maxunicode` is 65535.)

Comment: Python 2 doesn't have very good Unicode support for characters outside the BMP. If you really need it you need a build of Python with 32-bit Unicode characters. Otherwise start using the later versions of Python 3.

Comment: @CJ59 Woops. That is what I meant... still doesn't do that

Comment: `>>> print re.sub(ur'[\U0001f469]+', u'', text) == u'something'` resolves to `True` for me in linux

Comment: @jwodder: beat me to it  I bet these are internally stored as 2-byte *surrogate characters*, and the `re` treats them as 2 separate characters as well – i.e., removing the `\u0001`'s first.

Comment: @CJ59 Then I guess you are not using python 2.7? I fixed my tags

Comment: `Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) [GCC 7.3.0] on linux2` is my header. I assumed python2 from your print statements.

Comment: Oh wait, *not* the `\u0001` – it never *sees* these. It substitutes the proper surrogates first, and *then* replaces these. Bracketed by `[..]` so one at a time, first the high order then the low order one.

Comment: Screams text formatting error to me.  Would it be prohibitive to convert all the unicode-compliant text to ascii and then search for the appropriate strings?  Not elegant, but might get around the 2-byte surrogate-esque issues?

Comment: `re.sub(ur'\U0001f469+', u'', text)` works as expected so the first character set should be replaced by something like `re.sub(ur'(?:\U0001f469|\U0001F60C)+', u'', text)` to work correctly.

Comment: @Mark_Anderson Good idea...

Comment: If you plan to remove all the emojis, this worked for me: `rx = ur"(?:{})+".format("|".join(map(re.escape,exclude_list)))` and then `re.sub(rx, u'', text.decode("utf8"))` (in Ubuntu, Python 2.7.12, GCC 5.4.0). I used regular `re` library. If you declare your string as a Unicode string, `text = u'something'`, you won't need `.decode("utf8")`.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew this looks helpful.

Comment: Just checking - did you see the answers? Do they help? If not, what is missing?

Answer (score 3):

In most builds of Python 2.7, Unicode codepoints above 0x10000 are encoded as a [surrogate pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+010000_to_U+10FFFF), meaning Python actually sees them as two characters. You can prove this to yourself with `len(u'\U0001F469')`.

The best way to solve this is to move to a version of Python that properly treats those codepoints as a single entity rather than a surrogate pair. You can compile Python 2.7 for this, and the recent versions of Python 3 will do it automatically.

To create a regular expression to use for the `replace`, simply join all the characters together with `|`. Since the list of characters already is encoded with surrogate pairs it will create the proper string.

```
subs = u'|'.join(exclude_list)
print re.sub(subs, u'', text)
```

Comment: I did not know that 2.7 could be compiled with 4 byte unicode support, and I definitely did not know that Ubuntu was distributing python2.7 with that enabled. Learn something new every day.

Comment: @CJ59 that's one of the best reasons to contribute to StackOverflow, the opportunities to learn are endless. Hardly a day goes by when I don't learn something new myself.

Answer (score 2):

The old 2.7 regex engine gets confused because:

1. Python 2.7 uses a forced word-based Unicode storage, in which certain Unicode codepoints are automatically substituted by surrogate pairs.
2. Before the regex "sees" your Python string, Python already helpfully parsed your large Unicode codepoints into two separate characters (each on its own a valid – but incomplete – single Unicode character).
3. That means that `[\U0001f469]+'` replaces *something* (a character class of 2 characters), but one of them is in your string and the other is not. That leads to your badly formed output.

This fixes it:

```
print re.sub(ur'(\U0001f469|U0001F60C)+', u'', text)  # something
# Removing only "" doesn't work 
print re.sub(ur'(\U0001f469)+', u'', text)            # some�thing
# .. and now it does:
something
```

because now the regex engine sees the exact same sequence of characters – surrogate pairs or otherwise – that you are looking for.

If you want to remove all emoji from the `exclude_list`, you can explicitly loop over its contents and replace one by one:

```
exclude_list = UNICODE_EMOJI.keys()

for bad in exclude_list:  # or simply "for bad in UNICODE_EMOJI" if you gotta catch them all
    if bad in text:
        print 'Removing '+bad
        text = text.replace(bad, '')
Removing 
Removing 
something
```

(This also shows the intermediate results as proof it works; you only need the `replace` line in the loop.)

Comment: Yes, creating a regular expression from a literal works great. The question expressed a desire to generate the expression from a list of characters, and it turns out that's much harder. I haven't cracked it yet.

Answer (score 2):

To remove all emojis from the input string using the current approach, use

```
import re
from emoji import UNICODE_EMOJI
text = u'something'
exclude_list = UNICODE_EMOJI.keys()
rx = ur"(?:{})+".format("|".join(map(re.escape,exclude_list)))
print re.sub(rx, u'', text)
# => u'something'
```

If you do not `re.escape` the emoji chars, you will get `nothing to repeat` error due to the literal chars messing up with the alternation operators inside the group, so `map(re.escape,exclude_list)` is required.

Tested in Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:36:49)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2.